# Split sorted Scala Sequence/Array according to gaps between elements

Tags: scala

I try to split an Array into chunks of elements which have a small distance to each other, i.e. where the difference to the neighboring elements are below a threshold.

i.e. using as constraint that the difference between two subsequent numbers mustn't exceed 2 would look like that:

```
val data = Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,20.0,21.0,22.0,23.0,24.0)
```

would become

```
Array(
  Array(1.0,2.0,3.0),
  Array(10.0,11.0,12.0),
  Array(20.0,21.0,22.0,23.0,24.0)
)
```

I managed to get an ugly solution using `span` which only works for two "groups" of numbers:

```
val data = Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,10.0,11.0,12.0)

// duplicate firs element
val modData = data.head +: data

val chunks = modData.tail.zip(modData)
  .map{case (next,prev) => (next,next-prev)}
  .span{case (_,gap) => gap<2.0}

val partA = chunks._1.map(_._1) // Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)
val partB = chunks._2.map(_._1) // Array(10.0,11.0,12.0)
```

Unfortunately I've no idea to solve this for more than 2 groups in a functional way.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Bear with me while I find the other one :)